# Using Javascript to set default filter in primefaces datatable

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a Primefaces datatable where one column has a Filter drop down menu. I want to set a default value for the filter on page load. By using `filterValue` and setting a default value for the option in the backing bean, the value is selected in the menu on page load however the datatable itself isn't actually filtered.

I have tried adding javascript to force the default filter on page load using the below example however it isn't working.

[setting default value in primefaces datatable Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450274/setting-default-value-in-primefaces-datatable-filter)

I have not worked with javascript much so my issue may be there.

JSF Page:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <ui:define name="header" >
            <h:outputScript name="common.js" target="body" />
        </ui:define>
    </h:form>


<p:dataTable var="dataItem" value="#{homepageBean.accounts}" 
         filteredValue="#{homepageBean.filterAccounts}" widgetVar="dataTableWidgetVar" >

        <p:column headerText="Status" id="statusCol" filterBy="status" 
                filterOptions="#{homepageBean.menu.statusOption}" 
                filterValue="#{homepageBean.defaultStatus}" >                                   
            <h:outputText value="#{dataItem.status}" />
        </p:column>             

</p:dataTable>      

</h:body
```

common.js page:

```
function setDefaultFilter() {
    dataTableWidgetVar.filter();   
}
```

homepageBean has applicable getters and setters. I am using Primefaces 4.0.

Comment: Where are you calling the setDefaultFilter() function? And are you certain that it is firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtFilterView.cars}" widgetVar="carsTable"
                     emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria" 
                     filteredValue="#{dtFilterView.filteredCars}">

            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel>
                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()" style="width:150px" placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column id="carId" filterBy="#{car.id}" headerText="Id" footerText="contains" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column filterBy="#{car.year}" headerText="Year" footerText="lte" filterMatchMode="lte">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <p:spinner onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()" styleClass="year-spinner">
                        <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Integer" />
                    </p:spinner>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column filterBy="#{car.brand}" headerText="Brand" footerText="exact" filterMatchMode="exact">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()" >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{dtFilterView.brands}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column filterBy="#{car.color}" headerText="Color" footerText="in" filterMatchMode="in">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Colors" onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()" panelStyle="width:125px" scrollHeight="150">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{dtFilterView.colors}" />
                    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column filterBy="#{car.sold}" headerText="Status" footerText="equals" filterMatchMode="equals">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <p:selectOneButton onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()">
                        <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Boolean" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sold" itemValue="true" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sale" itemValue="false" />
                    </p:selectOneButton>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{car.sold ? 'Sold': 'Sale'}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column filterBy="#{car.price}" headerText="Price" footerText="custom (min)" filterFunction="#{dtFilterView.filterByPrice}">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.price}">
                    <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" type="currency"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('input[id*="globalFilter"]').val('Orange');
            PF('carsTable').filter()
          });
    </script>
```

This is my group of code which is demonstrated default filter datatable in primefaces 5.0.
The original code are appear in [primefaces demo datatable filter](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml). Different between developed code and original code are only jquery part. If you use Primefaces 4.0 or newer(5.0), you must use `PF('dataTableWidgetVar').filter()` instead of `dataTableWidgetVar.filter()`

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('input[id*="globalFilter"]').val('Orange');
            PF('carsTable').filter()
          });
    </script>
```

Comment: not working with me it gives
 Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined